# How can I make a conditional loop?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I have an array that contains different number of items every time. And I need to put this condition on the way of it:

> *"if the number of items are less than 2, then print `nothihg`, if the number of items are between 2 and 4, then print the first two items, if there are 5 items, then print all items"*.

Noted that the max number of array's items is `5`.

```
$myarr = ["one", "two", "three"];
foreach($myarr as $item){
    if( count($myarr) >= 2 && count($myarr) < 5 ){
        echo $myarr[0].PHP_EOL;
        echo $myarr[1];
    } else if( count($myarr) == 5 ){
        echo $myarr[0].PHP_EOL;
        echo $myarr[1].PHP_EOL;
        echo $myarr[2].PHP_EOL;
        echo $myarr[3].PHP_EOL;
        echo $myarr[4];
    } else {
        echo "nothing"; 
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've used `echo $var[i]` statically. How can make it shorter and dynamical?

Comment: Use `elseif()`. And don't see reason for loop here.

Comment: Homework or job interview? Either way, to start with, you should only enter the loop if you have 2 or more values.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Neither.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Agreed, the `if` should be first and have the `foreach` inside.

Comment: @Yupik I've edited my question, you meant like that?

Comment: As @Yupik already wrote. Whats the reason for the loop?

Comment: I am confuse too, why the loop? explaining the reason can lead to better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many ways to skin this cat. These are my two cents:

#### Clean and readable version

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three"];

$count = count($array);
$iterations = 0;

if ($count < 2) {
    echo 'nothing';
} else {
    $iterations = $count <= 4 ? 2 : $count;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
    echo $array[$i] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/CWHuj

#### More compact, harder to read and full of bad practices:

*Note: This version was just for fun. Writing code like this in any other context should be illegal.*

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three"];
$count = count($array);
if (!$iterations = $count < 2 ? 0 : ($count <= 4 ? 2 : $count)) echo "nothing";
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) echo $array[$i] . PHP_EOL;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/N1fnv

Comment: @MartinAJ - I just saw that you changed the criteria for the question from _"5 items or more"_ to just _"5 items"_? That actually made the question incomplete. What it there are more?

Comment: Yes, there are 5 items in the array atmost.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following solution:

```
<?php
$myarr = ["one", "two", "three"];
$items_count = count($myarr);

if ($items_count < 2) {
    echo "nothing";
} elseif ($items_count >= 2 && $items_count <= 4) {
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_slice($myarr, 0, 2));
} else {
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, $myarr);
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/sG3Nm5

You don't need the `foreach` loop in this case. A simple list of conditions using `count` can do it.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest counting array everytime on each `if` block, count it once and storing it in variable is better approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
$output = '';
foreach($myarr as $k=>$item){
    if( count($myarr) >= 2 && count($myarr) < 5 && $k<2){
        $output .= $item.PHP_EOL;
    } else if( count($myarr) == 5 ){
        $output .= $item.PHP_EOL;
    } else if(count($myarr) <2) {
        $output .= "nothing"; 
        break;
    }
}
echo $output;
```